# Why I cannot see filesystem in result of df -h?

Tags: linux

When I list all of filesystems with `df -ha` command I can see following result:

```
user@server:~$ df -ah
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
proc                     0     0     0   -  /proc
sysfs                    0     0     0   -  /sys
udev                  3,9G  100K  3,9G   1% /dev
devpts                   0     0     0   -  /dev/pts
```

when i go to the `~/depoly` directory and execute `df -ha .` I can see following filesystem:

```
user@server:~/deploy$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
-                     229G  171G   46G  79% /
```

Can someone explain why I cannot see this **229G** filesystem `/` in the output of command `df -ha`?

Additional information about Linux distribution:

```
user@server:~/deploy$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.16.60-0.103.1-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)) #1 Thu May 16 19:52:34 UTC 2013
user@server:~/deploy$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.10 (lenny)
Release:        5.0.10
Codename:       lenny
```

Thank you!

EDIT:I haven't changed the directory during execution of the commands.
This is the copy paste from my command line (without any changes or edits):

```
user@server:~/deploy$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                  3,9G  100K  3,9G   1% /dev
user@server:~/deploy$ df -ha
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
proc                     0     0     0   -  /proc
sysfs                    0     0     0   -  /sys
udev                  3,9G  100K  3,9G   1% /dev
devpts                   0     0     0   -  /dev/pts
user@server:~/deploy$ df -ha .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
-                     229G  171G   46G  79% /
user@server:~/deploy$
```

Comment: Can you show what directory you where in for the 1st example. I don't know why it will matter, but you mention changing directory then it worked. So maybe it is relevant. I can not see anything in normal situation that will cause this. Can you show one code window, with a full transcript of what you did. Don't describe, show. And don't copy from memory, just do the experiment, and copy it into the question.

Comment: So my guess is something to do with mount-namespaces. However without seeing what you did (see previous comment), then I am unable to know if I am correct, or be more specific.

Comment: I've pasted the one window with three commands (I was still in the same directory)

Comment: The distribution information seems odd. The kernel version information from `/proc/version` suggests the distribution could be SuSE (or at least the kernel was compiled in a SuSE system), but `lsb_release -a` says it's Debian 5. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_5.0_(Lenny)), Debian 5's standard kernel version was 2.6.26, so the current kernel version is *older* than what Debian 5 is supposed to have. Are you within a `chroot` environment or some other special situation?

Comment: Tell us the operating system. Tell us any other information about the environment: security, virtualisation, containers, …

Comment: Thank you for your comments. This server is in our customer infrastructure and I cannot tell something more about it. I don't have access to the documentation. I was confused why I cannot see this filesystem in the list of all file systems. Probably it's chroot environment, but I'm not sure how to check it.

Comment: What is the output of `type df`?

Comment: Output of `ls -l /etc/mtab` please. It should be a symbolic link to `../proc/self/mounts`. If it's a regular file then the answer is that it's out of date with respect to the actually mounted filesystems, and I can write this up (with a solution)